# Does MAX affect other columns of a query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  WorkerId, MAX(  `TimeStamp` ) AS TimeStamp,  `Latitude` ,  `Longitude`
FROM  `workers_actions` 
JOIN worker_user w ON WorkerId = w.Id
WHERE  `ScannedTimestamp` >= DATE( NOW( ) ) 
        AND FarmerId=:farmer_id
        AND Longitude is not null 
        AND Longitude != 0 
        AND Latitude is not null 
        AND Latitude != 0 
GROUP BY WorkerId
```

Will i be getting `Latitude` and `Longitude` of the row with max timestamp or Is it not garaunteed?

Comment: If you have selected the column, of course it will appear in the returned results. However, having any rows that match your criteria is another issue.

Comment: Short answer: no. For long answer see the duplicate topic.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html - _If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate_